# Manhattan distance Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran77, fortran95

I would like to calculate the Manhattan distance between 2 arrays in Fortran according to the formula:

```
d = Sum(|P(i)-R(i)|)
```

So I made a code in Fortran:

```
function DistM(v, u, dim)
    integer dim
    real(8) v(dim), u(dim), DistM
    DistM=sum(abs(v-u))
end function DistM
```

I call this function by using this:

```
Coeff=DistM(tempvector1,tempvector2, dim)
```

But this doesn't seem to work (I don't get any return). I also tried by taking the power of 2 and then doing the sqrt of it, but it gets stuck at the sqrt then (if I run it in steps).
I tried another function and that one worked (see here after), but this one doesn't work :(:

```
function Roznica(v, u, dim)
        integer dim
        real(8) v(dim), u(dim), Rozn
        Rozn=sum((v-u)**2)/dim
end function Roznica
```

Anyone an idea?

Comment: Show us how you call this function.  Post an SSCCE -- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions

Comment: Updated High Performance Mark!

Comment: Post an SSCCE.  And explain what you mean when you write *I don't get any return*.  And format all code as code.

Comment: This Coeff should just give me a number... It's not such fancy code... When I call the Roznica function, that one works, but not the DistM function.
I think I know what the problem is in my code. I will check something and get back to it. Sorry for bothering

Comment: `real (8)` is not the same as `real*8` and is not portable.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a Manhattan distance function simply like this (with assumed-shape arrays you no longer have to use automatic arrays like you do, provided the function has an explicit interface):

```
pure function L1(v)
  real, intent(in) :: v(:)  ! <- shape assumed from actual argument
  real :: L1
  L1 = sum(abs(v))
end function
```

And then if you have two vectors you simply call the function as `foo = L1(p - q)`.

Comment: Note: this is just an example of how to do this in modern Fortran, not an answer to why your code does not work. As H.P. Mark said, more information is needed for that.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this. I have changed it!

About my code: I had a stupid tiny mistake in some other part and so now I solved it! Thanks to something H. P. Mark said (the return value thing).

thanks for the time anyway!

Comment: I've downvoted the question.  It irritates me beyond words to find that I have wasted my time trying to diagnose a problem in code that OP doesn't share.